# I got an unknown error on my coding for a C program

Tags: c, error-handling

Heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
int yearcounter = 0;
int monthcounter = 0;
int monthcounter2 = 0;
int extramonths = 0;
int monthsalive = 0;
int month;
int day;
int year;
int monthto;
int dayto;
int yearto;
printf("What date were you born? Enter mm/dd/fullyear with no dashes.\n");
scanf("  %d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);
printf("What is today's date?\n");
scanf("  %d/%d/%d", &monthto, &dayto, &yearto);

if

(year < 0 && year <= yearto);
year++;
yearcounter++;

if 

(month > 0 && month <= 12);
month++;
monthcounter++;

if 

(monthto > 0 && monthto <= 12);
{
monthto++;
monthcounter2++;
}
extramonths = monthcounter - monthcounter 2;

if

(extramonths <= 0);
{
yearcounter = yearcounter - 1;
}
monthsalive = yearcounter * 12;

printf("You've been alive %d years.\n", yearcounter);
printf("You've been alive about %d months.\n", monthsalive);
return 0;
}
```

And the error is:

> main.c:41:49: error: expected ';' before numeric constant
>   ; extramonths = monthcounter - monthcounter 2;

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Do those `if` statements look like any that you've seen in your textbook?

Comment: The compiler is telling you the file, the line and the column where the error is located! Something is missing between `monthcounter` and 2.

Comment: the error seems pretty descriptive to me, not sure why you said it's "unknown"

Comment: So, what is `extramonths = monthcounter - monthcounter 2;` supposed to mean? It is as meaningless to us as it is to the compiler. How do you expect people to "help you", when it is impossible to figure out what you were trying to do?

Comment: It is one of the ugliest pieces of code I've seen. Not to mention 'bugginess'.

Comment: Don't put semicolons at the end of every line. They do have a meaning in the language.

Comment: `monthcounter 2;` --> `monthcounter2;`

Comment: Baffling how code like this is possible.  Surely this can't be the second thing someone tries to compile after hello, world.

Answer (score 1):

What do you *think* this does??

```
if

(year < 0 && year <= yearto);
year++;
yearcounter++;
```

(Hints:  You have a semi-colon at the end of the if-statment, and you do NOT have brackets around the operations.)

You really want:

```
if (year < 0 && year <= yearto)
{
    year++;
    yearcounter++;
}
```

---

On this line:

```
extramonths = monthcounter - monthcounter 2;
```

Did you mean to multiple monthcounter by 2?  You need a ***multiplication operator*** for that!

```
extramonths = monthcounter - monthcounter * 2;
```

Or maybe you meant to use variable `monthcounter2`, in which case the space is just *bad*.

```
extramonths = monthcounter - monthcounter2;
```